# javaw.exe eating up my memory?

Tags: java, eclipse, javaw

Recently, javaw.exe processes have been taking over my computer and forcing me to exit out Eclipse and other applications due to low memory errors. Note that I am not maxing out the system at all, and am I working on some basic java programs, and I have 2-3 eclipse tabs open at a time max.

I have about 40-50 of these javaw.exe processes each take up 22K-26K of RAM, which eventually eats up 70-80% of my 8GB RAM on my machine. This is extremely frustrating as I cannot do any work like this. I was wondering if anyone else has experienced this and knows how to troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: This behavior looks like a virus to me.

Comment: May be there are some programs which are still running in the background.

Comment: Have you been able to isolate when they are starting?

Comment: I dont think its a virus, I have an anti virus software returning good results, and I had this problem for a couple of weeks now and I recently ran a system recovery to try to fix this, which didn't help.

Comment: It seems like they are starting when I compile and run a java program in eclipse and it is not always the case that when close the application, that the process closes as well.

Comment: There is no Help -> Performance in my Eclipse...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably launch the same program again and again from eclipse, and these programs never exit. Switch to the *Debug* perspective, and look at the *Debug* view. Kill all the processes that should not run anymore.

That said, `50 * 26KB` is very very far from `8GB * 80%`. And I doubt any Java program can be as light as 26KB.

Comment: But I do exit these programs. However, when I go to 'Windows Task Manager' the processes don't disappear after I exit the Java programs from eclipse...

Comment: How do you exit them? Do you press the square red "Terminate" button in the Debug view? A Java program terminates when System.exit() is called. If you just close the main window of your Swing/AWT application, for example, it doesn't exit.

Comment: Or it could be that some non-daemon threads continue to run in the background and prevent those programs from exiting.

Comment: I see, that is the root of my problem... In the past when I clicked 'x' on java applications it seemed to get rid of the process automatically, however now it is not the case. I will ue the red terminate button from now on... thank you!

Comment: Or you could fix your program and make sure System.exit is called when the frame is closed. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation%28int%29

Comment: Either make a System.exit call when main window is closed or identify background threads that continue running and devise a way to orderly terminate them when main window is closed. When all threads have terminated, the JVM will exit.

Answer (score 2):

It normally happens when you are doing multi threading. Make sure you stop all the threads which you have created by calling a `thread.interrupt()` for the the threads you have spawned before you end the application. That would remove `javaw.exe` from your Task Manager - Hope this will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JFrame, try this:

```
Main frame=new Main();//Main class extends JFrame.
frame.setdefaultcloseoperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally each eclipse instance should only have one `javaw.exe` process.. so check with a process explorer that they actually belong to eclipse and not some other background/zombie programs.

If you want to reduce javaw.exe memory, you can use `Help -> Performance -> Reducy Memory now`..

Note that this will reduce the used memory only of the actual eclipse's `javaw.exe` process..

Comment: @Majid Laissi, On Eclipse Mars.1 (4.5.1), there is no Help -> Performance option too. Why do your eclipse has this option?

Comment: yeah that was removed a long time ago